# Should I use sync AJAX to load the data that is required before anything else is triggered or not?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

Let's say I have a file named **index.txt** with some important values, which will be required to fulfill a certain condition that will trigger a function. So, I used AJAX to load the content of **index.txt**, but now I have a problem. I know that Synchronous AJAX is deprected ( as it is shown in Chrome's console ) and should not be used after all there are far more disadvantages than advantages ! But, I can't go with async since my function requires the data, before it executes anything else. So, my question is, how do I do that ? Should I use sync AJAX for this or not ?

Comment: delay init using a callback and/or promise to run the function once data are loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can solve like this. If you don't want mess with async stuffs. Just use this basic callback pattern.

```
let data = null;
const txtFilePath = '/data.txt';

function loadTxt() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      data = this.responseText;
      afterGetTextDataStuffs();
    }
  };

  xhttp.open('GET', txtFilePath, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
loadTxt();

function afterGetTextDataStuffs() {
  console.log('txt data is loaded...');
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: I can not understand you. This is asynchronous way not synchronous way. Can you give reference link?  Callback mechanism is related to asynchronous concept.

Comment: you can use more information in here about synchronous and asynchronous. And my solution totally asynchronous trust me :)